# Ionic not loading images correctly & is whitelisted

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This is a strange issue, the controller loops through an array which collects the url from the server for the images, then its put into src="https://www.socialnetwk.com/test.png" 
However it doesnt load those images. I inspect element, right click src=".." and open in new window. once in a new window and I refresh the ionic app page it load that image, that one image only that I

```
.controller('feedCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.result = "";
     $http.get('https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/feed_load.php').then(function(rest) {
        $scope.records = rest.data;
      });
    })
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="feed in records">

    <ion-list id="search-list5">
      <ion-item class="item-avatar" id="search-list-item12">
        <img src="https://www.socialnetwk.com/media/{{feed.profile_image}}">
        <h2>{{feed.firstname}} {{feed.lastname}}</h2>
        <p>{{feed.location}}</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <div style="margin: 0px; line-height: 250px; background-color: rgb(232, 235, 239); text-align: center;">
      <img style="width:100%;height:auto;" ng-src="https://www.socialnetwk.com/media/{{feed.media_file_format}}/{{feed.media_post_id}}{{feed.media_author_id}}.{{feed.media_file_format}}" />
    </div>
    <div class="item item-body" id="search-list-item-container3">
      <div id="search-markdown6" class="show-list-numbers-and-dots">
        <p style="margin-top:0px;color:#000000;">{{feed.mediatxt}}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add your html code as well in the question

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you include your path with `ng-src`. If you just use `src` you will have troubles.

```
<img ng-src="data.imageurl"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your URL(**https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/feed_load.php**) resquest in Postman and get this.

```
[
{
"firstname": "Casper",
"lastname": "Round",
}
]
```

So you don't have data you need.

Check Url.

Comment: Theres no point testing that url. Of course its going to change I keep editing that file!